# Example with p specifier in figure

Tags: floats

I'm looking for an example on how to use the specifier p in a LaTeX's figure. Moreover does it make sense to use both hp specifiers simultaneously in the same figure?

Comment: p should always be there to allow the figure to go to a float page too. see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2388

Comment: Not understood. It is just `\begin{figure}[p] `  vs `\begin{figure}[hp] `.  I'd say the former is only used when doing finishing touches on a project. In most cases you'd be using `[htp] ` or `[htbp] ` (not everyone likes bottom figures). Imo `[hp] ` does not make much sense compared to `[htp] `

Comment: Hello @daleif my goal is to understand with examples how the p specifier works

Comment: Why do you need examples for that? If only p is available the figure is 9laced on a page that only contains other figures or tables.

Comment: @daleif I tried to use it in a file where there are 2 figures, one with the option h and the other one with the option p. The figure with p is placed on a new page. Maybe if I organize the figures so that all of them have the p specifier, they will placed on the same page?

Comment: If space permits

Comment: thenk you so much @daleif

Comment: @daleif if h means "Place the float here, i.e., approximatelyat the same point it occurs in the source text (however, not exactly at the spot)", what does hp mean? Maybe h has a higher priority than p? By using hp I got the same result of h

Comment: See Peters answer which is also found in the manual for the memoir class. The need for h to become t, is because else a `[h] ` would never det placed. Also note that if at the bottom of a page, h is not the same as  b. h explicitly require there to be a certain amount of non float above and below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Float placement parameters are, and are checked in the following order.

1. If `!` is specified ignore most restrictions and continue.
2. If `h` is specified try to place the float where it is. If nothing else is specified change `h` to `t` (try the top of the next page).
3. If `t` is specified try to put it at the top of the current page.
4. If `b` is specified try to put it at the bottom of the current page.
5. If `p` is specified try and put it on a float page after the current page.
6. If necessary steps 3 and 4 are repeated at the start of each new page, followed by 5 at its end.

So, `\begin{figure}[hp]` will try and put the figure *here* and if that does not work then on the next page by itself.